# Using regsvr32 to register 32bit dll on 64bit Win 10

Tags: windows, dll

I have been read all the posts I could find thru Google on this issue, but still haven't found any ways to find the actual cause and remedy for it.

Allow me to break down the issue in a few layers below.

**[1] Situation**

I have a 32bit dll I have successfully registered on my machine two days ago(Let's say it's name is '32bit.dll'). But today, it just doesn't work. First, let me show 2 ways I've tried.

A) regsvr32 32bit.dll   (at the folder where 32bit.dll resides in)

B) regsvr32 '/path/32bit.dll' (at ~SysWOW64 folder, with correct path for 32bit.dll)

I know, many people say you have to be at ~syswow64 folder and then use regsvr32 'path/32bit.dll'. But I have successfully registered 32bit dll by just going to the folder where it is in, and doing A).

But today, for some reason, it doesn't work when I do either A) or B).

**[2] Errors**

When I do either, this is what happens in my computer
1) CMD processor consumes more than 60% of CPU and memory, and runs for a while.
2) It then gives out error messages. These include

"make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files"

"the paging file is too small for this operation to complete"

"Cannot find 'SHELL32.dll'"

"Cannot find 'SGService.dll'"

"Cannot find 'SGCrypto.dll'"

3) Then, when I clikc 'ok' on these error messages, computer screen goes black,and comes back afetr a few minutes.

4) When it comes back, the CPU and memory are still consuemed by the CMD processor even when I close the CMD window.

**[3] Thoughts**

I am baffled because doing A) caused no problem two days ago.
I've done System File Checker, DISM to repiar the System Image... etc, following this [post](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-missing-dll-files-errors-windows), but it did not really help anything.

I spent a whole two days so far to see the cause of this and solve the problem, register the dll and go on debugging.

Now I am beyond frustration; I just want to know what is the cause, why that happened, and how I can fix it. But I am such a newbie in this world, so asking for some help.

If you want me to try any other things and share with you what happens, please give me any suggestions.

Thank you for reading and help.

Best,

Sung

Answer (score 1):

Use the COMMAND prompt to find out what is really going on. Using Windows Explorer gives you false information!!! This applies to 32-bit and 64-bit, Win 7 and Win 10.

If you have previously successfully copied a file to %windir%\system32 (or %windir%\sysWoW64), then subsequently try to overwrite by copying another version using Windows Explorer, it will ask you to confirm that you want to overwrite it and will report that it has done so, and it will show you the date and file size of the new version in the right place. But it is lying!!!

From the COMMAND prompt, you will find it has really copied it to:
%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore\Windows !!! Some programs will find it in its new location  but most will use the original copy in %windir%\system32.

To do what you need, run COMMAND as Administrator, delete the copy you don't want and recopy the one you do want (and remove the one in the wrong place too, so it doesn't give you false information in future).

Good luck. Even if you have fixed your problem in the interim (or given up), this may help someone else ...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I solved the problem by going to registry, finding where dll was registered, go to that folder, unregister it with (resgvr32 /u), and registering again. I don't know what was wrong, but that solved it!